# Como puedo resetear los keys de un array para que comience desde cero?

Tags: php

Es que a la hora de eliminar los valores repetidos de un array con la funcion array_unique lo que hace a veces es cambiarme las llaves del array y me los revuelve, el problema es que a la hora de colocarlo en un for, obviamente me salta error. Les dejo el codigo:

```html
<?php
            $array_numero=[
               ['numero'=>12],  
               ['numero'=>12],
               ['numero'=>14],
               ['numero'=>14],
               ['numero'=>15],
               ['numero'=>15],
               ['numero'=>16],
               ['numero'=>16]
            ];


            for($i=0;$i<count($array_numero);$i++){
             $show[]=$array_numero[$i]['numero'];

             
            }

            var_dump(array_unique($show));

//y lo que me retorna es lo siguiente: 
array(4) { [0]=> int(12) [2]=> int(14) [4]=> int(15) [6]=> int(16) } 

?>
```

hay forma de resetear los keys o hay una mejor manera de simplificar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Qué te parece si, en vez de rellenar `$show` y después quitarle duplicados, lo rellenas directamente con valores únicos? Prueba así:

```
<?php

$array_numero=[
   ['numero'=>12],  
   ['numero'=>12],
   ['numero'=>14],
   ['numero'=>14],
   ['numero'=>15],
   ['numero'=>15],
   ['numero'=>16],
   ['numero'=>16]
];

$show=[];
for($i=0;$i<count($array_numero);$i++)
    if(!in_array($array_numero[$i]['numero'],$show))
        $show[]=$array_numero[$i]['numero'];
var_dump($show);
```

Obtendrás lo que creo que buscas:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(12)
  [1]=>
  int(14)
  [2]=>
  int(15)
  [3]=>
  int(16)
}
```

Aunque, bueno, con un simple `array_values()` se respondería más rápido a tu pregunta:

```
var_dump(array_values(array_unique($show)));
```